# ?? Coalesce for empty string?

Tags: c#, string, coalesce, null-coalescing-operator

Something I find myself doing more and more is checking a string for empty (as in `""` or null) and a conditional operator.

A current example:

```
s.SiteNumber.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "No Number" : s.SiteNumber;
```

This is just an extension method, it's equivalent to:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.SiteNumber) ? "No Number" : s.SiteNumber;
```

Since it's empty and not null, `??` won't do the trick.  A `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` version of `??` would be the perfect solution.  I'm thinking there has to be a cleaner way of doing this (I hope!), but I've been at a loss to find it.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this, even if it's only in .Net 4.0?

Comment: Just to tantalize you a bit, you can easily define custom, ad-hoc binary (and unary, for that matter) operators in F#. Here `let (|?) x y = if String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) then y else x` and use it like `s.SiteNumber |? "No Number"`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this.  You could make your extension method return a string or null, however, which would allow the coalescing operator to work.  This would be odd, however, and I personally prefer your current approach.

Since you're already using an extension method, why not just make one that returns the value or a default:

```
string result = s.SiteNumber.ConvertNullOrEmptyTo("No Number");
```

Comment: I think you're right, and this is the cleanest solution currently available that's still readable.  I'd love something like a `???` operator in C# 5 though, who knows.

Comment: and what would the ??? operator do? take default values in addition to nulls? sounds extremely complicated at best

Comment: With lambda expressions maybe?
For instance: assume "item" is nullable, then...

`item ?? x=> x.ToString() : null;`

Comment: @IsaacLlopis that ends up looking messy-er than OP's original snippet

Comment: I would prefer a name like `ReplaceNullOrEmptyBy()` because it's not conversion. But the concept itself has a weakness: It does not work if the `string?` variable should be replaced not by a string literal, but by another one or multiple chained `string?` variables, and finally by a string literal. The chained calls will create nullability warnings again.

Answer (score 211):

C# already lets us substitute values for `null` with `??`. So all we need is an extension that converts an empty string to `null`, and then we use it like this:

```
s.SiteNumber.NullIfEmpty() ?? "No Number";
```

**Extension class:**

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string NullIfEmpty(this string s)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s;
    }
    public static string NullIfWhiteSpace(this string s)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? null : s;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach seems more self-documenting so upvoted...

Answer (score 59):

I know this is an old question - but I was looking for an answer and none of the above fit my need as well as what I ended up using:

```
private static string Coalesce(params string[] strings)
{
    return strings.FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
}
```

Usage:

```
string result = Coalesce(s.SiteNumber, s.AltSiteNumber, "No Number");
```

**EDIT:**
An even more compact way of writing this function would be:

```
static string Coalesce(params string[] strings) => strings.FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: I like, but had to fix a compiler error and made it a bit more compact.

Comment: Why do you call this Coalesce when it doesn't bring the values together, but merely selects the one that isn't empty? It's a confusing name dude.

Comment: Because Coalesce is the term used by many databases to do the same operation (find first non-null value). Joining strings together is concatenation.

Comment: Best answer if you're `using System.Linq`

Comment: That's elegant, nice job.

Comment: string default is null, so this function requires either a `string?` return type or a `FirstOrDefault(..) ?? ""`

Answer (score 20):

I have a couple of utility extensions that I like to use:

```
public static string OrDefault(this string str, string @default = default(string))
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? @default : str;
}

public static object OrDefault(this string str, object @default)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? @default : str;
}
```

You could also use this if you want it to apply to any type:

```
public static T OrDefault<T>(this T obj, T @default)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default(T)) ? @default : obj;
}
```

Edit: Inspired by **sfsr**'s answer, I'll be adding this variant to my toolbox from now on:

```
public static string Coalesce(this string str, params string[] strings)
{
    return (new[] {str})
        .Concat(strings)
        .FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
}
```

Comment: I'm definitely using the "Coalesce" term, as it more closely resembles the intent of the null coalescing operator (??), though I changed it to "CoalesceTo."

Comment: What does the `@` prefix on the `@default` parameter do? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @druciferre - That just allows you to use `default` as a variable name even though it's a reserved keyword in C#.

Comment: Why do you call this Coalesce when it doesn't bring the values together, but merely selects the one that isn't empty? It's a confusing name dude.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - Because it approximates the standard T-SQL [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - Also because it specifically selects the *first* non-empty function in an arbitrary-length list. It's a subtle detail, but the T-SQL function works the same way. The name makes it intuitive to anyone who knows that function, with or without documentation.

Answer (score 9):

I simply use a NullIfEmpty extension method which will always return null if the string is empty allowing ?? (Null Coalescing Operator) to be used as normal.

```
public static string NullIfEmpty(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s;
}
```

This then allows ?? to be used as normal and makes chaining easy to read.

```
string string1 = string2.NullIfEmpty() ?? string3.NullIfEmpty() ?? string4;
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the advantages of the null-coalescing operator is that it short-circuits. When the first part isn't null, the second part isn't evaluated. This can be useful when the fallback requires an expensive operation.

I ended up with:

```
public static string Coalesce(this string s, Func<string> func)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? func() : s;
}
```

Usage:

```
string navigationTitle = model?.NavigationTitle.
    Coalesce(() => RemoteTitleLookup(model?.ID)). // Expensive!
    Coalesce(() => model?.DisplayName);
```

Answer (score 6):

A slightly faster extension method than proposed earlier perhaps:

```
public static string Fallback(this string @this, string @default = "")
{
    return (@this == null || @this.Trim().Length == 0) ? @default : @this;
}
```

Comment: Why not make use of [IsNullOrWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) rather than trim and length it.

Comment: `code`
public static string Coalesce(this string @this, string @default = "")
    {
        return (@this == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@this)) ? @default : @this;
    }

Answer (score 4):

how about a string extension method ValueOrDefault()

```
public static string ValueOrDefault(this string s, string sDefault)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return sDefault;
    return s;
}
```

or return null if string is Empty:

```
public static string Value(this string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return null;
    return s;
}
```

Didn't try these solutions though.

Comment: I like option #1 there, although I'd call it something more semantic like Or(), so I could write "string s = s.SiteNumber.Or("Default");"

Comment: Calling something `...OrDefault()` would be confusing if it didn't behave like the rest of the framework's `...OrDefault()` methods.  Like it or not, MS has given a specific meaning to that naming and deviating from that behavior in custom methods is unnecessarily confusing to users of your API.

Answer (score 4):

Since writing this answer I've improved my "coalesce" method considerably, and also abstracted it adding versions for generic types. My solution now consists of the three methods bellow:

```
public static string CoalesceWhiteSpace(this string str, params string[] strings) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        return str;
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strings[i]))
            return strings[i];
    return str;
}
public static T Coalesce<T>(this T v1, params T[] vs) {
    if (v1 is not null)
        return v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < vs.Length; i++)
        if (vs[i] is not null)
            return vs[i];
    return default;
}
public static T CoalesceDefault<T>(this T v1, params T[] vs) {
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(v1, default)) 
        return v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < vs.Length; i++)
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(vs[i], default))
            return vs[i];
    return v1;
}
```

The `CoalesceWhiteSpace` will accept an arbitrary number of strings to coalesce with a "source" string, considering whitespace as `null`. The same example used on the previous version of this post now looks like this:

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = "   ";
string s3 = "loudenvier";
string s = s1.Coalesce(s2, s3);
Assert.AreEqual("loudenvier", s);
```

The generic `Coalesce<T>` is similar but accepts any `nullable` type. And, of course, it can be used with strings also:

```
string s = null;
var v = s.Coalesce(null, null, "outro");
Assert.AreEqual("outro", v);
```

But also with any object:

```
object o = null;
object expected = new();
var v = o.Coalesce(null, null, expected);
Assert.AreSame(expected, v);
```

And, finally, the `CoalesceDefault` will coalesce an arbitrary number of objects by comparing it with it's default value (useful to use with non-nullable types which are initialized to their default values, like `DateTime`):

```
DateTime d = default;
var now = DateTime.Now;
var v = d.CoalesceDefault(new DateTime(0), d, now);
Assert.AreEqual(now, v);
```

It also works with strings:

```
string s = "  ";
var v = s.CoalesceDefault(null, null, "", "", null, " ", "   ");
Assert.AreEqual("  ", v);
```

Note: null, "" and " " are considered default string values, and, as such only the last string with multiple spaces is returned above!

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

I'm using a string Coalesce extension method of my own. Since those here are using LINQ, and absolutelly wasting resources for time intensive operations (I'm using it in tight loops), I'll share mine:

```
public static class StringCoalesceExtension
{
    public static string Coalesce(this string s1, string s2)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s1) ? s2 : s1;
    }
}
```

I think it is quite simple, and you don't even need to bother with null string values. Use it like this:

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = "";
string s3 = "loudenvier";
string s = s1.Coalesce(s2.Coalesce(s3));
Assert.AreEqual("loudenvier", s);
```

I use it a lot. One of those "utility" functions you can't live without after first using it :-)

Comment: I don't think you understand why they are using LINQ, and since parameters are evaluated before calls, your `s2.Coalesce(s3)` is run even when not needed as well. Better to use a `NullIfEmpty()` extension and `??`.

Comment: @NetMage I can guarantee you that the LINQ versions are a lot less performant than the one I presented. You can create a simple benchmark to test this if you wish. I suggest using https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet to prevent common pitfalls when writing benchmarking code.

Answer (score 0):

I like the brevity of the following extension method `QQQ` for this, though of course an operator like? would be better. But we can 1 up this by allowing not just two but three string option values to be compared, which one encounters the need to handle every now and then (see second function below).

```
#region QQ

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static string QQQ(this string str, string value2)
{
    return (str != null && str.Length > 0)
        ? str
        : value2;
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static string QQQ(this string str, string value2, string value3)
{
    return (str != null && str.Length > 0)
        ? str
        : (value2 != null && value2.Length > 0)
            ? value2
            : value3;
}


// Following is only two QQ, just checks null, but allows more than 1 string unlike ?? can do:

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static string QQ(this string str, string value2, string value3)
{
    return (str != null)
        ? str
        : (value2 != null)
            ? value2
            : value3;
}

#endregion
```

Comment: If you like short names you could call it `Or`, and I would use the `params` keyword, like the other answers, which avoids duplicate definitions for multiple parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have long since replaced this name with "FirstNotNull" in my own usage.

On `params`, it would be better not to do that for the default scenario or two, as `params` causes an array to be allocated needlessly when you only have the default one or two inputs. After that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to turn some of the answers in to a helper extension class with generics for a even broader usage:

NOTE: for an explanation of short-circuit method the see the [wensveen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44717244/4249111)

```
// classic
public static string Coalesce(this string s, params string[] strings)
  => s.Coalesce(string.IsNullOrEmpty, strings);

// short-circuit compatible, for expensive string getting
public static string Coalesce(this string s, params Func<string>[] getters)
  => s.Coalesce(string.IsNullOrEmpty, getters);

// generic
public static T Coalesce<T>(this T value, Func<T, bool> isEmpty, params T[] values) where T : class
  => isEmpty(value) ? values.FirstOrDefault(val => !isEmpty(val)) : value;

// generic, short-circuit compatible
public static T Coalesce<T>(this T value, Func<T, bool> isEmpty, params Func<T>[] getters) where T : class {
  if (isEmpty(value))
    return getters
      .Select(getter => new Lazy<T>(getter))
      .FirstOrDefault(val => !isEmpty(val.Value))
      ?.Value;

  return value;
}
```

Example usage:

```
string result = s.SiteNumber.Coalesce(s.AltSiteNumber, "No Number");

string result = s.SiteNumber.Coalesce(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, s.AltSiteNumber, "No Number");

string navigationTitle = model?.NavigationTitle.
  Coalesce(() => RemoteTitleLookup(model?.ID), () => model?.DisplayName);

Player player = player1.Coalesce(p => p?.Score > 0, player2, player3);
```

(PS: I think I'm getting bit off topic here using generics. Am I overthinking this?)

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qavCode", SqlDbType.Char, 11)).Value = (object)(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rf.Request.QavCode) ? null : rf.Request.QavCode) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Don't know, maybe I'm too late answering this question but in my example I mixed the regular ternary ?: to the null-coalescing operator ?? in order this one to work with empty strings too.
Hope it helps :)