# c# Coalesce operator crashes on null

Tags: c#

pulling data from database I have this this

```
Result = main.Verified.Equals("1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "Good Sale" : "Bad Sale";
```

Problem is that `main.Verified` is sometimes null and so it crashes with object reference error

What is an easy way to fix?

I was looking at this, but I'm not sure it has the best solution
[?? Coalesce for empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420125/coalesce-for-empty-string)

Comment: if main.Verified is null do you consider it as "Good Sale" or "Bad Sale"?

Comment: Technically, you are using a ternary. *not* a null coalescing operator

Comment: @ShaiAharoni     -   null should not happen , it is bad data so think think Bad sale

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  -  thats right   - thx

Comment: @JeremyMiller "Shouldn't happen" as in "there's an unfixed bug somewhere" or "shouldn't happen" as in "something unexpected happened"? If it's the first, then you **want** it to crash here (rather than just ignore the issue) and the solution is to fix the bug. If it's a "bad sale," is there some kind of sensible action that your program can do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the const value string first in the comparison.

```
Result = "1".Equals(main.Verified, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    ? "Good Sale" 
    : "Bad Sale";
```

This works because `string.Equals()` will always return false when compared with `null`. However, calling `.Equals()` on a null reference will always throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: ok, but I will never pull in "1"  ,     so what can i do to first check for null?

Comment: You could write a more complex condition. `Result = (main != null && main.Verified != null && main.Verfified.Equals("1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ? "Good Sale" : "Bad Sale";`

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this:

```
Result =
    (main.Verified ?? "")
        .Equals("1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? "Good Sale"
        : "Bad Sale";
```

Comment: thanks I am also now hearing that per a business rule if it is null that i need to log it , so essentially if it is "1" is good,  2 -9  bad sale ,  and null is neither  it gets some log to db or email or file ...